# How can I use information from a variable-length list of categories?

Tags: categorical-data

I am building a machine learning model using information from the sales of a store. One information that is important in my scenario is the category of each of the products associated with the sale.

If each sale was only associated with one item, then I would just use that item's category as a categorical variable. However, given that a sale might be associated with a variable number of items, each belonging to possibly different categories, I wonder how I could be using information for the category of all items in my model. Right now I'm simply selecting only one of the categories, and discarding the others, but that obviously throws away important information. I thought about maybe using some embedding related procedure for encoding that information, but I'm not too sure about it.

Comment: Have you tried one-hot encoding your categories?

Comment: Yes. However, my main doubt is about how to deal with the fact that the amount of categories that is going to be present is variable. So even if one-hot encoding each of them, I would end up with a variable length amount of one-hot encoded variables.

Comment: But the number of possible categories is constant, right? i.e. you have a set of categories $C$ and each item $i$ in a sale belongs to one of the categories $c_i \in C$? If that's the case, you can have a feature that counts the number of items of given category for given sale. Alternatively you can simply make this feature binary, i.e. representing if given category (or item of that category) is present in a given sale. 

Unless I misunderstood the problem and you're saying that, during inference, you might get an item(s) that are assigned to a category that was unseen in the training data?

Comment: No, that actually answers my question. I think I was over complicating the problem in my head thinking about some other steps that happen related to this category information and wasn't clearly seeing this alternative. Thanks for the help!